# Flow builder - Pass multiple key-values

Tags: visual-workflow

i would like to implement a flow that takes in input multiple product_ids-quantities.
I can create variable of type text but i can't see how to pass an array key-value pairs.

Is it possible only using flows?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer assumes the client of the flow has some control over marshaling the arguments.

**Option 1: ApexTypes**

Flows support ApexTypes as a data type. The documentation for this is in [Help](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_considerations_apex_data_type.htm&type=5). An example is [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_build_extend_apex_type.htm&type=5)

In your case, the ApexType (which needs to be an outer class) would have two fields: ProductId and Quantity.

Then, the flow variable is a collection of the ApexType available for input

**Option 2 - Use a Proxy SObject**

- The `OpportunityLineItem` (or `OrderItem`) have both a Quantity field and a reference to a Product2
- Your client would construct a collection of proxy Sobjects and pass to the flow.

Comment: Intuitively I went for Option 2. 
We used OrderItem as Object Collection Variable that lives only to be used as an object.
This was the best option since I don't want to use Apex.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: great - works well as long as you don't need IDs